Are Scoped Background Services good choice for long running task based on client request?
I'm building an ASP.NET Core application and need to manage long-running tasks initiated by client requests (task running until client close browser or detect interactivity) through a SignalR hub. I understand that BackgroundService typically runs as a singleton, but I'm considering using scoped services within it for tasks real time hardware communication. Here's a simple setup:
SignalR Hub: Initiates tasks based on client connections.
Singleton BackgroundService: Manages long-running tasks/scoped services.
Scoped Services: Used within the BackgroundService for operations requiring scoped lifecycle management, such as client duplex communication with a hardware and database.
Example:
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public Task StartTask(string taskId)
    {
        BackgroundTaskManager.StartTask(taskId, Context.ConnectionId);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class BackgroundTaskManager
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public BackgroundTaskManager(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    public void StartTask(string taskId, string clientId)
    {
        using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyScopedService>();
            service.PerformTask(taskId, clientId);
        }
    }
}

Is using scoped services within a singleton BackgroundTaskManager a good practice for handling such tasks? What are the potential pitfalls of this approach?

I think that's a valid approach. It's discribed in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service

Is using scoped services within a singleton BackgroundTaskManager a good practice for handling such tasks
Yes, consuming scoped services in the hosted services is just fine and is covered in the docs - for example in the section Consuming a scoped service in a background task of the Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core doc:

To use scoped services within a BackgroundService, create a scope. No scope is created for a hosted service by default.

What are the potential pitfalls of this approach?
I would argue that the "tick"/"iteration" at least in some should be granular enough, especially if you are using something like EF Core with "standard" scoped setup (EF Core uses change tracking for DML operations and having a single scoped instance can lead to memory-leak like behavior). I.e. PerformTask should not perform all the processing for the whole app time since otherwise the scoped dependencies will become effectively captive ones.
